Did the city of Rome have a hospital?
Is there any evidence of physicians working in the equivalent of a modern hospital in 1st century city of Rome?
If yes, are there any ruins of such place?

Do you mean the city of Rome specifically or in any Roman city of the period?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia:Hospital is insufficient.

Thanks. I edited it to make it clear the question refers to the city of rome

There were no 'modern hospitals' before the 20th century. Before scientific medicine, hospitals were where poor people went to be nursed when they were ill.


Question:
Did Roman have an equivaled to a modern hospital in the first Century AD?

Short Answer:
The Roman Empire in the first century did not have public health infrastructure.  There was a less formal service provided through  religioius temples to Asclepius.  There was also medical services provided for active duty military.
Answer:
The term physician was coined in the 13th century.

Science Diction: The Origin Of 'Physician'
In the 13th century, Anglo-Normans appropriated the French physique, or remedy, to coin the English physic, or medicine, which is still in dictionaries today.

Depends how you want to interprete "modern hospital".  Public health was non-existent to the Roman world in the first century AD.  Romans started building Hospitals for public health only after adopting Christianity after the First Council of Nicaea in AD 325. At that time Modern day Turkey contained the Roman capital and that is where they started building Hospitals.  The first hospital didn't reach the City of Rome for several hundred years after Nicaea.

Hospitals
The declaration of Christianity as an accepted religion in the Roman Empire drove an expansion of the provision of care.[20] Following the First Council of Nicaea in AD 325 construction of a hospital in every cathedral town was begun, including among the earliest hospitals by Saint Sampson in Constantinople and by Basil, bishop of Caesarea in modern-day Turkey.

However. The Romans in the first century had adopted a God from Ancient Greece called Asclepius the healer-god.  Temples to Asclepius functioned as centers of medical advice, and healing.  Probable wouldn't term them as modern hospitals but certainly related.

Asclepius
The rod of Asclepius, a snake-entwined staff similar to the caduceus, remains a symbol of medicine today. Those physicians and attendants who served this god were known as the Therapeutae of Asclepius.

There were also military hospitals called valetudinarium but these were for soldiers, not the public.
The first hospital in Europe was established in Rome in 727 to serve Saxon pilgrims visiting St. Peter’s tomb. The oldest European hospital still standing is the Hôtel Dieu in Paris near Notre Dame, which tradition suggests was built in the 7th century (651 AD), earliest existing records of it functioning as a hospital support 829 AD.

If the 651AD date for the Hotel Dieu is correct, it would have been established before the one in Rome. Or, if the 829 date is correct that would make it 9th century.

I'm confused about your incidental remark that, in 325 CE modern-day Turkey contained the Roman capitol... Constantinople, yes, I guess, but not Rome, which was still "a thing" in 325 CE?

@paulgarrett The founder of the Byzantine Empire and its first emperor, Constantine the Great, formally moved the capital of the Roman Empire to the city of Byzantium in 330 CE.  However; Constantine did not govern from the city of Rome.  Constantine governed from what is modern day Turkey.  Which is why the first Church council which Constantine called was not in modern Italy but a suburb of Constantinople or Nicaea.  the capital of the Empire is where the Emperor lives.
